# laptop can't find wifi but connects with ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop

I have windows 10 on my PC before and after the format.

I have format my PC lately and after all the set up I tried to connect to the home WiFi(connect regularly before) but suddenly the PC won't even find the WiFi on the WiFi list. but when I've connected an Ethernet cable the WiFi worked perfectly. I've deleted and updated the WiFi adapter from the device list already and it did nothing. please help.

Comment: Is it a hidden network?

Comment: What is the make and model of your router?

Comment: no, everyone can connect the network.

Comment: how do I check the make and model?

Answer (score 1):

Please try these troubleshooting steps that may help.

1. Make sure the router SSID broadcast is on.
2. Change the wifi channel to see if it resolves the problem.
3. Enter the SSID and WPA2 password manually and see if the laptop connects.
4. Temporarily turn off the encryption.
5. We go into device manager & check updates for wifi drivers, we may need to simply update the driver.
6. We go to **Settings - Network & Internet - Status - Change Adapter Options**, then right-clicked '**Ethernet**' and disabled it.  We do the same with wifi. Then we (with Ethernet still disabled) enabled wifi. It should re-connect to your wifi after a while.
7. We have to disconnect our Ethernet cable from our laptop and follow the steps: 
   **Start>Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Manage Wireless Networks** and remove all wireless connections by right click on it and select **Remove network** from the drop down menu. After doing this, close the windows and scan for the wifi networks. 
   Click on the available network and select connect. After a while, we will be asked to give a password for our wifi connection. Type the password and click on connect button. And now will be connected to our wifi network via wireless.
8. First is to disconnect the internet cable from the laptop then uninstall/reinstall the wifi adapter.
   Go to Device Manager and uninstall the wifi adapter.
   Once uninstalled, reboot the laptop and it should reinstall the driver automatically.
   After the reboot do try connecting to your wireless network again.
   If all these will not work, do also make sure that the wireless adapter is enabled. Depending the model of your laptop there should be key combinations on how to enable/disable it.